# Google sheets IFS and AND query

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to mod a formula in google sheet to substract a value based on the value of another column
Column E has the amount of hours: 3, 4, 5, 9 for example
If the hours are between 4 and 5 I need to substract 0.25 , if between 5 and 6 - 0.50 and if > 8 - 0.75
this is what I did:
=ArrayFormula(if(len(E2:E) ,(ifs((E2:E=0),IFERROR (1/0),AND(E2:E > 4 , E2:E < 6 , E2:E-0.25) or (E2:E > 6,E2:E < 8 ,E2:E-0.5) OR (E2:E > 8,E2:E-0.75)))))

could anyone please help me figuring out what I'm doing wrong? thank you

Comment: I have a good idea what you are asking but a picture or a table would be extra helpful! Also FLOOR(E2 - 3)*(-0.25) should cover both -0.25 and -0.5, but a modification is needed depending on whether you subtract 0.25 or 0.5 when E2 is exactly 5.

Comment: thank you, could put on a table but its only a column with hours.. can be 4.4, 5.6 .. this is why I put > 4 and < 6 to include all. Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily achieve this with `vlookup`.

Build a static array `{}` of two columns with your limits and results for the `vlookup` range:

```
={4,-0.25;5.0001,-0.5;6.0001,0;8.0001,-0.75}
```

[image]

Then a `vlookup` to test inputs. My input figs are in col G, and the `vlookup` is in an `arrayformula` in cell `H1`:

```
=arrayformula(if(G1:G<>"",iferror(vlookup(G1:G,{4,-0.25;5.0001,-0.5;6.0001,0;8.0001,-0.75},2,1),),))
```

[image]

You can then add the result to your existing formula.

**UPDATE**

This takes the hour value from col E and makes the required subtraction. Add this formula to cell `F1` and clear all cells below:

```
=arrayformula({"Adjusted hours";if(E2:E<>"",E2:E+iferror(vlookup(E2:E,{4,-0.25;5.0001,-0.5;8.0001,-0.75},2,1),),)})
```

[image]

Comment: Can't really guess the results as the hours can vary.. anything above 6 and below 8 will need to subtract 0.5 and anything from 8 and above - 0.75

Comment: You can modify the array according to your required parameters. If above 5 and above 6 need to subtract -0.5, you can ignore the 6: `{4,-0.25;5.0001,-0.5;8.0001,-0.75}`

Comment: See UPDATE in the solution.